# Datomic Backup is failing and I don't know why

Tags: backup, datomic

What I really want to do is move a mess of dataomic data from my lab hosts to my new staging hosts.

Lab is a computer in a closet in our office.  Staging is our new hardware at a colocation site in the suburbs.

I *think* backup is the best way to handle this, but I'm open to other ideas.

I'm doing this from my transaction host in lab (credentials sanitized)

```
$ bin/datomic backup-db "datomic:sql://drone-develop?jdbc
:postgresql://[redacted]:5432/datomic?user=[redacted]&password=
bob+zazz@35szoonn_ZZQ" file:/tmp/backup
```

- /tmp/backup is created.
- Then the process blows up:

  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
  FATAL: password authentication failed for user "datomic"
  ...
  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication 
  failed for user "datomic"
  ...

The port is open between transaction host and the db server (redacted).
Using psql I can login with those credentials, from db host and local workstation.

Log files

```
datomic-pro-0.8.4020/log/2013-11-07.log
...
2013-11-07 21:37:00.121 INFO  default    datomic.slf4j.bridge - SLF4J Bridge installed
2013-11-07 21:37:02.305 INFO  default    datomic.kv-cluster - {:tid 10, :pid 7864,
:event :kv-cluster/retry, :StorageGetBackoffMsec 0, :attempts 0, :max-retries 
20, :cause "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Self-inflicted: the password contains a '$'.  Escaping that with '\' fixes the issue.